# Deleting records in relation with other tables

Tags: mysql, table, uniqueidentifier

I need suggestions on deleting records in relation with other tables

For example i have a client in the clients table and this client has bills, payments, wire transfers etc... so this client id is in relation with other tables, it seems like i will never be able to delete this client because of past records, because if i delete this client other tables wont be able to inner join the clients table and all the records which has this client id will be vanished :)

I hope i was clear enough on my explanation,
My question is; what is the right way in a situation where i have to delete a client record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the best way is: **Do not delete the records**.

As far as I understand your are talking about accounting and financial information. Usually this information cannot be deleted, at least for a minimum space of time, 5 years on my country. (More time for medical & health products)

If, for some reason, a customer becomes inactive, use a `status` field to mark him.

> ```
>         status | description
>         -------|-------------
>           0    |   Active
>           1    |   Blocked
>           2    |   Deleted
>           n    |   ....
> ```

However, if you **must** delete all this information. I'd suggest you to define and develop a function (stored procedure, udf, etc) that takes care of all required changes in your DB. May be saving historical information, just to know when, who and why this records has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks McNet's, it seems like using a status field and mark the clients is the best way, i can mark a client "passive", "deleted", etc... and then use that field to show/hide/never show a client,  i thought too about moving the past records but then past reports,sums will have butterfly effect and they will change too :), and i dont want to join another table, i like to keep it simple as much as it is possible

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, and unless there's good reason for it, I agree with @McNets: **don't delete** the data, just flag it with a certain status.

If you still need to delete the `client`, and you don't want to delete all the data from the referencing tables, one possibility is to have one "fake" client, that gets assigned all the bills, payments, etc. Let's call it `(client_id = 99999999, client_name = '(deleted client)')`.

When you delete any row on table `client` (let's say client_id = 1234), you have your system (most probably by means of a trigger) change the `client_id` of all the other referencing tables from 1234 to 99999999.